# Fire drywall in bathroom

Tags: bathroom, drywall

We are insulating the external wall of a bathroom, and I know we should put *green* drywall.  A neighbour gave us a couple of *red* drywall, saying it would do the job as well.  Is it true?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean **purple** rather than **red** drywall?  I see that you are from Spain, so I don't know if this answer will apply in your country - but here in the USA, the difference is that **green** drywall is *moisture-resistant*, but it is not water*proof*.  **Purple** drywall has superior moisture- and mold-resistant characteristics that make it much more suitable for use where it might be in contact with water.

Comment: I did not know about the purple one.  No, I mean the fire resistant one.

Answer (score 0):

Fire-resistant drywall (known as Type X here in the USA) is not water-resistant, so I don't recommend it in a bathroom - **unless** you "layer" the drywall. Install the *red* fire-resistant drywall against the studs, and then install a layer of the *green* drywall on top of the fire-resistant sheets. This will provide both fire- and water-resistance.

Comment: They do make type x green and purple board here in the states.